# How to get last index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to get a last index.

Example.

```
"Hello, World~! this is a sample"
```

I will search "this".

Result is 4 (this -> 's' index)

Comment: What code are you using to search? Why not just subtract the length of _this_ from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
DECLARE @text VARCHAR(100) = '"Hello, World~! this is a sample"'
DECLARE @ser VARCHAR(50) = 'this'

SELECT LEFT(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(@text,CHARINDEX(@ser,@text),LEN(@ser))),1)
```